# xarray merge slow seems not working to conbine different lat lon netcdf

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have this code below, use xarray to merge a bunch of different variables and different lat.lon together of netcdfs. it ruuning forever and never ends but no error messages.

```
import xarray as xr
import glob
import numpy as np

datasets_WFHS= (xr.open_mfdataset(fname) for fname in
    glob.glob(r'Z:\travelers\shp\test\*WFHS.nc'))

datasets_WFHS=xr.align(*datasets_WFHS, join='outer')

dataset_WFHS =np.maximum.reduce([d['AREASCORE'] 
    for d in datasets_WFHS])

datasets_AF= (xr.open_mfdataset(fname) 
    for fname in glob.glob(r'Z:\travelers\shp\test\*AF.nc'))

datasets_AF=xr.align(*datasets_AF, join='outer')

dataset_AF=np.maximum.reduce([d['AREAFUEL'] 
    for d in datasets_AF])

datasets = xr.merge([dataset_WFHS, dataset_AF], join='outer')

datasets.to_netcdf(r"Z:\travelers\shp\test\results.nc")
```

Comment: There is not a question in this post. I suggest spending a bit more time formulating  a question that we can help answer.

Comment: It’s not working with no error messages that’s the question

Comment: I have experienced longer merge times (and eventual memory errors) when I have two lat lon fields that are very close but not exact due to some previous round off error, at which point a lot of time is spent creating a very fine mesh.

I would suggest testing your work through with smaller files and compare the lat lon fields before merging.